# Problems with msdeploy.exe

Tags: asp.net, deployment, msdeploy

What a tool...

Anyway, I absolutely cannot get msdeploy to work, and so I am trying to use this command-line option to at least trigger a connection: "msdeploy.exe -verb:dump..."

Yet, still got errors. It seems that I need an 'appHostConfig' parameter, but nothing I enter is accepted. Currently my site does not use "Default Web Site", but rather I deleted that root and created my own "MyCompany" which points to C:\MyApp and just reads back a simple index.html file. I thought that appHostConfig=MyCompany would work, but it doesn't. Neither does appHostConfig=abc.com/MyCompany or other varients. Help?

Comment: How are you launching MSDeploy? From the command line? VS publish dialogue?

Comment: Please include the full command line that u r using, also is this on the same machine, and r u executing this from an Admin prompt?